# How to get version of installed minifilter driver?

Tags: windows, cmd, driver, minifilter

I'm having some minifilter drivers installed on my system. I want to find the version of minifilter driver which is installed. I tried `fltmc` command to load/unload the drivers.
Is there any command to find the version of installed minifilter drivers on windows ?

Answer (score 3):

I suppose that the easiest solution to this problem is the following:

1. list running minifilters via `fltmc`,
2. lookup service keys for the listed filters (`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\<filter_name>` should do the job),
3. get file names of the corresponding drivers,
4. look into the version info inside their files.

If you mean the value of the `Version` member of the `FLT_REGISTRATION` structure, this field should always be filled with `FLT_REGISTRATION_VERSION`.

Comment: actually, my problem is the installed driver is older and the the driver file present on the system is newer one. So i want to check the version of installed driver & the driver file present on the system. I'm to get version of the driver file which is on the system, but I'm not able to get version of same installed driver.